# Becoming HIPAA Compliant

Tags: compliance, hipaa

What is required to become HIPAA Compliant?

Do I need to take a test or do I just need to follow a certain set of guidelines?

EDIT: Just to provide my background. I am a small IT Firm and we would like to expand into the medical field and work with all the smaller medical places.

Comment: Have you tried a Google search or logging into hhs.gov? They even have a handy [checklists](http://www.ihs.gov/hipaa/documents/IHS_HIPAA_Security_Checklist.pdf).

Answer (score 10):

HIPPA isn't a certification, it is a set of regulations for proper handling of personal health information.  The requirements vary based on what your role is and what data you handle.  I would recommend visiting the [Health Information Privacy](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/) section of the Health & Human Services site for more info.

It also might not hurt to hire someone to evaluate your compliance if you are still confused about it as it is a legal requirement for handling certain types of health information.

Answer (score 9):

The Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act better known as HIPAA, has been called to live by the government to protect patient's private information. HIPAA is aimed at healthcare professionals and staff who have access to patient information. HIPAA certification is a certification designed by private firms accompanied by training and testing. HIPAA certification is not yet officially approved by the government.

There are a set of tests you need to take to get this certificate from one of the private firms which issue HIPPA certificates. There are three levels:

- Certified HIPAA Professional (how to behave as professional under the HIPPA regulations)
- Certified HIPAA Security Specialist (how to make your organisation compliant)
- Certified HIPAA Administrator (aimed at administrative personnel and nurses)

Each level has it's own training and set of goals you need to achieve.

Comment: The edit to the OP's question means that this answer is no longer helpful. OP does not want to become personally certified, he wants his business to be HIPAA compliant.